# Items aren't updated in UI after updating them in CoreData

Tags: core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have List of items and fetch them from CoreData

```swift
@FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                }               
            }
}
```

I try to upate all items but UI shows old values. Item entity has new values in sqlite.

```swift
let request = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entity: Item.entity())
request.propertiesToUpdate = ["timestamp": Date()]
do {
    try viewContext.execute(request)
} catch {
    let nsError = error as NSError
    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
}
```

Comment: This has been asked in one for or another many times. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63101162/7129318).

Comment: @Yrb Thanks, I added my answer there.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data batch updates do not update the in-memory objects. You have to manually refresh afterwards.

Batch operations bypass the normal Core Data operations and operate directly on the underlying SQLite database (or whatever is backing your persistent store). They do this for benefits of speed but it means they also don't trigger all the stuff you get using normal fetch requests.

You need to do something like shown in Apple's Core Data Batch Programming Guide: Implementing Batch Updates - Updating Your Application After Execution

[Original answer](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/items-aren-t-updated-in-list-after-updating-them-in-coredata/7710/7711)

```swift
do {
    let request = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entity: Item.entity())
    request.resultType = .updatedObjectIDsResultType
    request.propertiesToUpdate = ["timestamp": Date()]

    let result = try viewContext.execute(request) as? NSBatchUpdateResult
    let objectIDArray = result?.result as? [NSManagedObjectID]
    let changes = [NSUpdatedObjectsKey: objectIDArray]
    NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: changes, into: [viewContext])
} catch {
    let nsError = error as NSError
    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
}
```